# How can I change the title style in navigationOptions of react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

for example font color and fontSize maybe fontFamily?

```
static navigationOptions = {
headerStyle: {
  backgroundColor: '#27A9E1',
  shadowColor: 'white',
  elevation: 0,
},
title: 'PROFILE',
(for example I tried something like titleStyle and headerTitleStyle: but didn't work???)
```

};

Comment: if you check `package.json`, what version of `react-navigation` are you running?

Answer (score 1):

the `headerTitleStyle` option should work. This is actually not hard to find in the [source code](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/e4a7b7e073302bf970f1f1112b46a36873f7fc4a/src/views/Header/Header.js#L93).

usage:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  headerTitleStyle = { your styles here}
}
```

Comment: I should've mention that I also tried that but doesn't seem to work.. I trie like this 
headerTitleStyle: {textAlign: 'center', alignSelf:'center', color: 'white', fontSize: 25,},

Comment: what part of it doesn't work? the text color and fontSize should work, but aligning won't work afaik.

Comment: the whole thing I even tried keeping only color and fontSize but it's not working.. headerStyle works for the background color of the header but not headerTitleStyle

Comment: you'll probably need to do a bit of debugging to work this out, or share the code you're using.

Answer (score 1):

It seems *headerTitleStyle* can only be set in *navigationOtions* once per navigator. Search in your code for an earlier occurrence of *navigationOtions* with *headerTitleStyle* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom component to render the Header.

```
// ProfileScreen.js
static navigationOptions = {
    header: props => (
      <Header
        {...props}
        title="PROFILE"
      />
    )
  };
```

This is your custom component header, Header.js

```
 //Header.js
    ...
    render() {
      const { title } = this.props
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.yourstyle}>{title}</Text>
        <View>
      )
    }
```